# How i can Compile telegram cpp client given by telegram github?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, compilation, client, telegram

I find telegram clients sample in c++ languages. first i install TDlib on Ubuntu 20.4 by the following commands :

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt-get install make git zlib1g-dev libssl-dev gperf php cmake g++
git clone https://github.com/tdlib/td.git
cd td
git checkout v1.6.0
rm -rf build
mkdir build
cd build
export CXXFLAGS=""
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=/usr/local ..
cmake --build . --target prepare_cross_compiling
cd ..
php SplitSource.php
cd build
cmake --build . --target install
cd ..
php SplitSource.php --undo
cd ..
ls -l /usr/local
```

after install i want to compile official telegram simple sample given by telegram in the following address :

```
https://github.com/tdlib/td/blob/master/example/cpp/td_example.cpp
```

after that i want to compile this example by the following command :

```
gcc td_example.cpp
```

but unfortunatelly i get many errors. can anybody please tell me how i can compile this file on ubuntu via terminal console ?

.

Comment: Would help if you could post the first few errors in your question.

Comment: i got many errors and unfortunately i cant get few error to send those.